# set data link file instead of connection string

Tags: delphi, ado

delphi 7,

when opening a connection to db, you can choose data link file, or Connection String.

when the program compiles , it connects with connection string. on run time, there is a need to change to an user input udl.

what is the property to change in order to change the conneciton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below assumes you have an instance of TOpenDialog (OpenDialog1) for selecting a file, and an instance of TAdoConnection (AdoConnection1). It sets connection string according to the selected .udl file.

```
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    AdoConnection1.Connected := False;
    AdoConnection1.ConnectionString := 'FILE NAME=' + OpenDialog1.FileName;
    AdoConnection1.Connected := True;
  end;
```

Comment: in delphi-7 there isn't disconnect. hmmm

Comment: @none; no problem. Write AdoConnection1.Connected := False instead of AdoConnection1.Disconnect.